# How do i get move up and down button in modifiers?

Tags: interface

I want these buttons in modifier panel in Blender 3.0 how to get them?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As moonboots said, those button have been removed in favor of a drag-and-drop functionality. The new method is a marked improvement in my opinion, but if you still would like to get a similar UI back, the only way I know of is the [Modifier List](https://github.com/Symstract/modifier_list) add-on (free). In addition to some other tools, it also has a "List" mode where, instead of the default "Stack" view, it displays your modifiers in a list and exposes their settings one-by-one when selected. That view still has the up-and-down buttons to arrange the modifiers:

[image]

One big potential downside to that mode is that its author has to update the add-on if a new option is added or removed from a modifier, since the exposed settings are shown in a custom view. A compromise would be to have the list view enabled in the sidebar (<kbd>N</kbd> panel) but not in the *Properties* panel:

[image]

Comment: Thank you. This is somewhat useful.

Answer (score 7):

These buttons don't exist anymore, they have been replaced by these dots on the right that allow drag and drop:

[image]

Comment: ...but on ebay...!?!? Amazon...!? are you really sure? :D

Comment: @ Chris yes but only available for Amiga

Comment: you were an amiga boy!? now you disappointed me for the first time  i had an Atari 1040 ST.....

Comment: I began with Apple (but I remember brands like ZX Sinclair, TRS, Goupil, TO7...)  ;)

Comment: me too...but it was no original Apple...but one of the cheap rebuilds of an Apple II ;) no normal human being could afford an original apple at that time... :D

Comment: @moonboots Ok. I kinda realised that but thought maybe there is some addon to enable like modifier-addon. These buttons were really easy to use on small screens when lot of modifiers are open. Dragging modifiers is not very accurate yet in Blender i feel.

Comment: @Chris I'm an Atari guy, too. Atari 1040 STF, and I had the SH205 hard drive with 20 MB capacity  And both monitors, color and bw.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: yep, had also both monitors...after i saved my money for 3 month ;)

Comment: @Chris, don't lie, that's not what I heard, I heard you attacked old ladies to steal their money  :((

Comment: @moonboots: that was a secret i only told you and you abused my trust. So now i will go and buy some cryptonite.... but by the way, not only old ladies, also young and weak ones....‍♂️

Comment: @Christ, I know, you even stole babies money from what I've heard, aren't you ashamed